# purrr safely over a function and save the links which are giving errors

Tags: r, purrr

I have some links:

```
myLinks = c("https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelavit/todas-las-zonas/l", 
"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelles-de-foix/todas-las-zonas/l", 
"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/vilafranca-del-penedes/todas-las-zonas/l", 
"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/vilobi-del-penedes/todas-las-zonas/l"
)
```

One of the links is returning an error but I don't want to remove it, I just want to store the link so I can inspect it further.

Data/Code:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4536L)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

collectZonaLinkData <- function(zona_url_to_get){
  
  remDr$navigate(zona_url_to_get)
  #click on Distrito
  remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div')$clickElement()
  html_zona_full_page = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_html()
  
  Zonas_Names = html_zona_full_page %>% 
    html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem.is-checked') %>% # only interested in the checked name boxes
    html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal') %>% 
    html_text()
  
  Zonas_Link  = html_zona_full_page %>% 
    html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem.is-checked') %>% 
    html_attr('href') %>% 
    paste("https://www.fotocasa.es", ., sep = "")
  
  zonas = cbind.data.frame(Zonas_Names, Zonas_Link)
  return(zonas)
}
```

I can run the following:

```
out = map(myLinks, ~ collectZonaLinkData(.x)) %>% 
  set_names(myLinks) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "ID")
```

Whic gives the following error:

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :    arguments imply
> differing number of rows: 0, 1

The problem url is the following:

```
collectZonaLinkData(myLinks[3])
```

How can I wrap the `collectZonaLinkData` inside `safely` and make sure that the `Zonas_Link` contains an `NA` in the data frame.

i.e. running the following:

```
myLinks = myLinks[1:2]
out = map(myLinks, ~ collectZonaLinkData(.x)) %>% 
  set_names(myLinks) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "ID")
```

Gives me the output for 2 links which work:

```
                                                                                ID       Zonas_Names
1        https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelavit/todas-las-zonas/l        Torrelavit
2 https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelles-de-foix/todas-las-zonas/l Torrelles de Foix
                                                                        Zonas_Link
1        https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelavit/todas-las-zonas/l
2 https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelles-de-foix/todas-las-zonas/l
```

The 3rd link doesn't work so it can collect the `ID` but for `Zonas_Names` and `Zonas_Link` I would like an `NA` in these columns.

I am not sure if I should wrap the `safely()` function around the `Zonas_Names` and `Zonas_Links` inside the  `collectZonaLinkData`?

Expected output:

```
                                                                                            ID       Zonas_Names
            1        https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelavit/todas-las-zonas/l        Torrelavit
            2 https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelles-de-foix/todas-las-zonas/l Torrelles de Foix
            3 https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/vilafranca-del-penedes/todas-las-zonas/l
NA
                                                                                    Zonas_Link
            1        https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelavit/todas-las-zonas/l
            2 https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/torrelles-de-foix/todas-las-zonas/l
            3 NA
```

**EDIT:**

Ouput:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  `https://www.fotocasa.… `https://www.fotocasa.es… $Zonas_Link         `https://www.fotocasa.e… `https://www.fotocasa.e… $Zonas_Link       
  <lgl>                   <fct>                     <fct>               <lgl>                    <fct>                    <fct>             
1 NA                      Torrelles de Foix         https://www.fotoca… NA                       Vilobí del Penedès       https://www.fotoc…
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can wrap the function as input to `possibly` or `safely`

```
pcollectZonaLinkData <- possibly(collectZonaLinkData, 
   otherwise = tibble(ID = NA_character_, 
    Zonas_Names = NA_character_, Zonas_link = NA_character_))
```

and then use this function in `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
out <- map(myLinks, ~ pcollectZonaLinkData(.x)) %>% 
  set_names(myLinks) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "ID")
```

Comment: I think this is close to what I want but it gives me the data in a slightly different format (i.e. the data frame is wrong - I have added an EDIT to show what it looks like)

Comment: @user113156 can you try the update